# I would like to know if ServicePartitionClient class is thread-safe

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

In my understanding, based on online information, ServicePartitionClient class is meant to be reused multiple times.

However I cannot find in the microsoft documentation if this class is thread-safe or not.

If not, I would like to know what is the common best practice to reuse such a class in a microservices environment: maybe `lock() { ... }` every time or create a new instance per call (not very useful in my case).

Thank you very much.

(at this moment in my code I'm using some static instances, and all appears to work correctly, but maybe it's going to fail under load later...)

EDIT:
I understand in some cases the class can be easily reused even if not thread safe (for example a background thread working on some queue can instantiate the class once and reuse it with no problem).

But in other common cases (such a microservice that receive a call and may need to call another microservice) reusing may become more complicated if the class is not thread safe.

It's in the nature of this class to perform I/O operation, so I think that a lock could be quite expensive due to race conditions.

Also in my understanding this class maintain in its state the last-resolved address for its target-service, and re-resolve it only in case of non-successful calls. Therefore instantiating a new class every time can be also expensive because I think in this case the newly instantiated ServicePartitionClient class will be forced to contact the naming-service every time to resolve the service address (two network roundtrips).

So I think Microsoft should really provide a thread-safe implentation for this class.

(sorry for my bad english)

Comment: It's a bit hard to say because some parts of the MSDN documentation standard doesn't seem to apply to learn.microsoft.com, in particular you can see the MSDN page for the [FileStream class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.110).aspx) has a specific note about thread safety but the learn.microsoft.com page for the [FileStream class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.7) has no such thing, so the absence of this note does not indicate that it is threadsafe.

Comment: The class has [no settable properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.communication.client.servicepartitionclient-1?view=servicefabricsvcs-2.5.216)

Comment: That doesn't mean it is thread safe, the question is if it mutates internal state and how safe that is.